# Large enough bounding box for graph cluster

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-drawing, neato

I want to programmatically draw graphs (preferably using `dot`, `gvpack` and `neato`). I can generate the graph structure using a library, then write a file containing the graph described with `dot`, and then pack all graphs in the same file. Each graph has a label that acts as a title for it, which contains essential information and cannot be omitted. Unfortunately, the label is sometimes too wide.

[image]

Now, the result is as I expected. However, I would like the bounding boxes of the individual graphs to be larger in order for them to fit the entirety of the "title". Then, I would like the graphs to be arranged in such a way that not even the bounding boxes overlap.

But I don't know how to tell `dot`, `gvpack` and/or `neato` to use a bounding box large enough to fit each individual graph while disallowing overlap.

Can this be done? If so, how? Thank you!

## MWE

These are the only two trees of 4 vertices in the image above.
File `tree_04_00.raw`:

```
graph {
    layout = neato
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        label = "idx= 0, centre=(0,1), centroid= (0,1)";
        nd_0 [label= "0"];
        nd_1 [label= "1"];
        nd_2 [label= "2"];
        nd_3 [label= "3"];
        nd_0 -- nd_1;
        nd_0 -- nd_3;
        nd_1 -- nd_2;
    }
}
```

File `tree_04_01.raw`:

```
graph {
    layout = neato
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label = "idx= 1, centre=(0), centroid= (0)";
        nd_4 [label= "0"];
        nd_5 [label= "1"];
        nd_6 [label= "2"];
        nd_7 [label= "3"];
        nd_4 -- nd_5;
        nd_4 -- nd_6;
        nd_4 -- nd_7;
    }
}
```

To actually make the image above, I execute the following commands:

```
# dot for each .raw file
$ dot -Tdot tree_04_00.raw > tree_04_00.dot
$ dot -Tdot tree_04_01.raw > tree_04_01.dot
# now pack all the graphs
$ gvpack -array_it20 tree_04_*.dot > trees_04.dot
# now run neato
$ neato -n2 -Tsvg trees_04.dot > trees_04.svg
```

The result of the last command is shown in the image above.

## Software

I'm using

- neato - graphviz version 2.43.0 (0)
- dot - graphviz version 2.43.0 (0)
- gvpack (unknown version)
- gvpr version 2.43.0 (0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**neato** has problems with clusters.
Old (pre 2..43.0?) versions did not "do" clusters at all(?), and the current version incorrectly handles cluster labels (the problem you have encountered).

Below is a **gvpr** (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) program that takes the output from any of the layout engines in **dot**/**xdot** format i.e. with **pos** values (positions calculated), and

- wraps the result in two nested clusters (Two nested clusters make for better padding)
- moves any graph labels to the inner cluster
- moves "top-level" graphs, nodes, and edges to the inner cluster
- adjusts node labels to prevent "label modification" if **gvpack** will be used downstream
- sets **bb** values for both nested clusters

**neato** will do better with these clusters because **neato -n/n2**

The **gvpr** program ( clusterWrap.gvpr):

```
//
// creates clusters around the entire graph, allowing user to save graph label
// also "fixes" node labels by instantiating default values (\N -> actual node name)
//
BEGIN{
  graph_t aGraph, Root, innerCluster, outerCluster;
  node_t  aNode;
  edge_t  anEdge;
  int     i, cnt, topNode[], topSubgraph[], topEdge[];
  float   delta=8., deltaX, deltaY;
  string  st;
  string  copyAtt[int];

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  split("label|lheight|lwidth|lp|bb", copyAtt, "|");

//  deltaX=delta;
//  deltaY=delta;
}
BEG_G{
  Root=$G;
  // get graphs, nodes, and edges(?) directly "under" Root graph  
  for (aNode=fstnode($G);aNode;aNode = nxtnode(aNode)){
    topNode[aNode]=1;
  }
  for (aGraph = fstsubg($G); aGraph; aGraph = nxtsubg(aGraph)) {
    topSubgraph[aGraph]=1;
  }
  // we will find top-level edges later
  
  // create wrapper clusters
  outerCluster=subg(Root,"clusterPad000");
  innerCluster=subg(outerCluster,"clusterWrapper000");

  if (hasAttr(Root, "layout")){
    Root.layout="neato";  // other values (including "") cause problems with later execution
  }
  //Root.OLDbb=Root.bb;
  // "move" attribute values to new cluster
  for (copyAtt[i]){
    if (hasAttr(Root, copyAtt[i])){
      st=aget(Root, copyAtt[i]);
      aset(innerCluster, copyAtt[i], st);
      aset(Root, copyAtt[i], "");      
    }
  }
  innerCluster.peripheries=0;
  // create a pad/margin between the two new clusters
  outerCluster.bb=(string)((float)xOf(llOf(innerCluster.bb))-delta) + "," +
          (string)((float)yOf(llOf(innerCluster.bb))-delta) + "," +
      (string)((float)xOf(urOf(innerCluster.bb))+delta) + "," +
      (string)((float)yOf(urOf(innerCluster.bb))+delta);
}
N{
  $.OLDpos=$.pos;
  // "fix" node labels by creating explicit label
  if (hasAttr($, "label") && ($.label!="")){
    print("//  starting label: ", $.label);
    $.label=gsub($.label, "\\\\N", $.name);   // ugh, backslashes
    $.label=gsub($.label, "\\\\G", $G.name);  // ugh, backslashes    
  }else{
    print("//  starting label: >", $.label,"<");  
    $.label=$.name;
  }
}
E{
  // find all edges defined directly under Root
  if (isSubedge(Root, $)){
    topEdge[$]=1;
  }  
}
END_G{
// now move graphs, nodes, and edges "under" inner cluster
  for (topSubgraph[aGraph]){
    print("//  cloning subg :", aGraph.name);
    clone(innerCluster, aGraph);
    delete(Root, aGraph);
  }
  for (topNode[aNode]){
    print("//  moving node :", aNode.name);
    subnode(innerCluster, aNode);
  }
  for (topEdge[anEdge]){
    print("//  moving edge :", anEdge.name);
    subedge(innerCluster, anEdge);
  }  
}
```

One modified input file with cluster reference removed:

```
graph {
    layout = neato
    //subgraph cluster_0 {
        label = "idx= 0, centre=(0,1), centroid= (0,1)";
        nd_0 [label= "0"];
        nd_1 [label= "1"];
        nd_2 [label= "2"];
        nd_3 [label= "3"];
        nd_0 -- nd_1;
        nd_0 -- nd_3;
        nd_1 -- nd_2;
    //}
}
```

A modified version of your command stream to show **gvpr** usage:

```
# dot for each .raw file
$ dot -Tdot tree_04_00.raw |gvpr -cf clusterWrap.gvpr > tree_04_00.dot
$ dot -Tdot tree_04_01.raw |gvpr -cf clusterWrap.gvpr > tree_04_01.dot
# now pack all the graphs
$ gvpack -array_it20 tree_04_*.dot > trees_04.dot
# now run neato
$ neato -n2 -Tsvg trees_04.dot > trees_04.svg
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, but the output I get in my computer is not what you show in the picture. I get two bounding boxes for each graph, and the labels (except '0') are missing. Could it be due to different versions of the software?

Comment: My apologies.  I failed to note that I removed the clusters from your input, leaving the labels at the Root-graph level.  I will edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Now it works perfectly, thank you! for sharing your knowledge with the community. This will be very helpful for me in the future and I'm sure it will be useful for other users too.